# How to use $\epsilon$-$\delta$ to show that following is less than $\epsilon$?

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, epsilon-delta

I try to $\epsilon$-$\delta$ to show that if I fix $\alpha$ small enough, for $\forall \epsilon>0$, there exists a $N$ such that $k>N$, I want
$$\frac{c}{\alpha}\exp(-2^k)+\exp\left(-\frac{1}{\alpha}\right)\le \epsilon$$
where $c>0$ is a constant.

I think I just need to let $\frac{c}{\alpha}\exp(-2^k)<\epsilon$ which is
$$2^k>\log\left(\frac{c}{\alpha \epsilon}\right)$$
But I do not know how to deal with $\exp\left(-\frac{1}{\alpha}\right)$. This term is small enough...

***The statement:***

For $\forall \epsilon>0$, we set $\epsilon-\exp\left(-\frac{1}{\alpha}\right)>0$, then we can find $$2^k>log(\frac{c}{\alpha(\epsilon-\exp(-1/\alpha))})$$ such that
$$\frac{c}{\alpha}\exp(-2^k)+\exp\left(-\frac{1}{\alpha}\right)\le \epsilon$$

Comment: This result seems wrong. What if $\epsilon<\exp(-1/\alpha)$?

Comment: Do you mean $\forall \epsilon > 0, \exists a > 0$?

Comment: @TedShifrin Suppose that $\alpha$ is small enough, like 0.

Comment: "Like $0$"? Please reconsider.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you have stated the problem, the inequality doesn't hold when

$$\varepsilon -\exp\left(-\frac{1}{\alpha}\right)\le 0$$

since, assuming $\frac c \alpha>0$, $\forall k, \: \frac{c}{\alpha}\exp(-2^k)>0$.

The problem should be stated as follows

> $\forall \epsilon>0$, there exist $\alpha>0$ small enough and $N$ such that $\forall k,\:k>N$
> $$\frac{c}{\alpha}\exp(-2^k)+\exp\left(-\frac{1}{\alpha}\right)\le \epsilon$$
> where $c>0$ is a constant.

Then fixed $\varepsilon>0$, we need to set $\alpha$ such that

$$\varepsilon -\exp\left(-\frac{1}{\alpha}\right)=\varepsilon_2 >0$$

and, assuming $\frac c \alpha>0$, we obtain

$$\frac{c}{\alpha}\exp(-2^k)+\exp\left(-\frac{1}{\alpha}\right)\le \varepsilon \iff \frac{c}{\alpha}\exp(-2^k)\le \varepsilon_2 \iff k\ge \frac1{\log 2}\log\left(\log\left(\frac{c}{\alpha \varepsilon_2}\right)\right)$$

The case with $\alpha <0$, if necessary, can be discussed in a similar way.

Comment: This is not consistent with the way the question was written. You're reversing the order of the quantifiers.

Comment: @TedShifrin Yes I understand your observation, I make this point more clear.

Comment: As long as I'm complaining, you're now assuming $c>0$ in your original remark. However, I believe it fails even when $c\le 0$.

Comment: @user Thanks. I think you are right.

Comment: @TedShifrin Yes, I just want my result is less than $\epsilon$ under the right condition. My original condition may be in a wrong order.

Comment: @TedShifrin Yes I made that assumption, I revise it.

Comment: @user I am a little bit confused about $\epsilon_2$. Can we use one $\epsilon$?

Comment: @Hermi I've introdced it only to simplify the notation, since we need that $\epsilon -\exp\left(-\frac{1}{\alpha}\right)>0$ this value is fixed and then we can denote it as $\varepsilon_2$.

Comment: @Hermi As you have noticed I'm also assuming $\frac c \alpha>0$ since I'm assuming this is seems the most intesting case. Anyway we can also extend to the case with $\alpha <0$.

Comment: @user I write a new "statement" below my question based on your answer. Do you mean this one?

Comment: @Hermi There is also an issue with your final derivation for $k$, check my expression and let me know if you agree with that.

Comment: @Hermi You can fix the first part of your question with the statement $$\forall \epsilon > 0, \exists a > 0 \ldots$$ As noticed if necessary we need to discuss separately the case $\alpha <0$.

Comment: @user How about $k$? Do not need to $\exists k>...$? I think we can assume $\alpha>0$ in my case.

Comment: The statement is $$\forall \varepsilon >0 \: \exists \alpha>0 \: \exists N\: \forall k\: k>N\:\ldots$$